# Why is the Microsoft SQL Server 2016 full-text index not crawled regularly?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, full-text-search

I have a **full-text catalog** which has one **full-text index** based on **3 columns** of a table. The table is the customers table and the columns are Name, Surname, Fullname. From the log files I can see that the index was updated on

```
23 October at 00:48
22 October 18 times between 13:00 and 23:36
--- gap ---
1 to 11 September daily and multiple times daily
--- gap ---
24 to 31 August daily and multiple times daily
--- gap ---
1 February to 17 July daily and multiple times daily
```

On the same SQL server but in the different database another full-text catalog has a similar update pattern.

1. The catalog has no schedule.
2. The index has change tracking set to automatic
3. We do use SSMS
4. The customers table is not modified (no columns added / removed)

Yesterday I updated a surname from "old surname" to "new surname" column in the index.

```
UPDATE customers SET Surname='new surname' WHERE ID = 12345 AND Surname='old surname'
```

Returns the new surname:

```
SELECT surname FROM customers WHERE ID = 12345 -- returns "new surname"
```

Using CONTAINS keyword, nothing is returned (even 24 hours after making the change) for new surname

```
SELECT Surname FROM customers C WHERE CONTAINS(Surname, 'new surname')  -- returns nothing
```

But

```
SELECT Surname FROM customers C WHERE CONTAINS(Surname, 'old surname')
```

still returns the "old surname"

I **do not want to manually** rebuild the catalog (by running ALTER FULLTEXT CATALOG)

I would like to understand why the index is not being crawled regularly and why the index was updated sporadically starting from 17 July?

Answer (score 0):

When did the last crawl run? :

```
SELECT  
    CatalogName      = fc.name,
    fi.change_tracking_state_desc,
    TableName        = t.name,
    IndexName        = i.name,
    LastCrawlEndDate = fi.crawl_end_date
FROM    
    sys.fulltext_indexes fi
    JOIN sys.tables t ON t.object_id = fi.object_id 
    JOIN sys.fulltext_catalogs fc ON fi.fulltext_catalog_id = fc.fulltext_catalog_id
    JOIN sys.indexes i ON fi.unique_index_id = i.index_id AND fi.object_id = i.object_id
 WHERE  
    fi.is_enabled = 1
    AND fi.crawl_end_date <= DATEADD(DAY, -14, GETDATE())
    AND t.name = N'Customers'
 ORDER BY 
    fi.crawl_end_date, t.name, i.name;
```

Sometimes, performing a full re-population can fix the problem:

```
ALTER FULLTEXT INDEX ON dbo.Customers  
   START FULL POPULATION;
```

Ref.: [Troubleshoot Full-Text Indexing Failures](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/search/troubleshoot-full-text-indexing?view=sql-server-ver15)

Comment: The crawl ran last on 23 October. Why did the crawl not run since yesterday 25 October after I updated the customer's surname?

Comment: https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/123418/will-a-full-text-catalog-with-track-changes-auto-automatically-update-if-change